# replacement inside parallel command string

Tags: quoting, variable, wget, gnu-parallel

I want to download multiple files and save them to the md5 sum of its name:

```
cat list | parallel -j4 "md5=$(wget -O - {} | tee tmpfile_{#} | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1); mv tmpfile_{#} $md5"
```

but the problem is that bash seems to execute the wget stuff before execution of parallel replaces `{}`... so wget wants to download from `http://{}`

so how can parallel replace its variables before the execution of the subcommand?

Answer (score 5):

some trial and error later:

```
cat list | parallel -j4 'md5=$(wget -O - {} | tee tmpfile_{#} | md5sum); mv tmpfile_{#} ${md5%% *}'
```

just replace `"` with `'` does not allow bash to replace something first

Comment: You might also want to read about [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: [Following the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) or [a guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is usually better than doing trial-and-error